# AWS Route-53 DNS Server IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'm using Route-53 as a DNS management service.
I have a problem that I'm not really sure how to solve it. I've come here to seek ideas.

I have a partner who wants an IP address of the DNS server, so that they can integrate their on-prem DNS server, to what I'm using(Route-53). This is not possible as Route-53 doesn't give an IP address for accessing the DNS servers. This is because it's a managed service. How can I get IP address for the Route-53 DNS servers so that my integrating partner can use to integrate the DNS server from their end to mine(Route-53)?

I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from AWS docs:

> `10.0.0.2`: Reserved by AWS. The IP address of the DNS server is the base of the VPC network range plus two. For VPCs with multiple CIDR blocks, the IP address of the DNS server is located in the primary CIDR. We also reserve the base of each subnet range plus two for all CIDR blocks in the VPC. For more information, see Amazon DNS server.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your hosted zone is private, as if it was public, your partner wouldn't need to do any special configuration (unless they don't allow querying public DNS in their network).

If this is a private DNS, I think what you want is to setup a Route 53 Resolver.  Specifically, you would want an inbound endpoint setup in your VPC.  This will give you a specific IP address that you can provide to your partner.  If you haven't already, you'd then need to configure network routing between your VPC and your partner's network (via a tunnel or peering).

AWS has a couple user guides for this, see below:

- [Route 53 Resolver Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resolver.html)
- [Route 53 Resolver announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-route-53-resolver-for-hybrid-clouds/)

Comment: I can see while creating a Route-53 resolver, a target IP address is required for the on-prem DNS server. Unfortunately, the partner can't give me their on-prem DNS IP address.

Comment: An outbound endpoint would require an IP for the on-prem DNS server but you don't need that.  If you just setup an inbound endpoint, it shouldn't require any on-prem configurations as it only responds to DNS queries and does not forward the request anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a try.

Comment: @dckr9 Hi, did you find a way to get the IP Address.